# How do I get column names of two tables at a time

Tags: mysql, sql, popsql

How do I get the column name of two tables in a single query ?

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where table_name = 'table_name';
```

This works for single table. But if I try

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where table_name = 'table1'
AND
SELECT column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where table_name = 'table2';
```

This throws error.

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'table2' ' at line 5
Error Code: ER_PARSE_ERROR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different queries will be put together using `UNION ALL` (or `UNION` only if it's necessary to exclude identic values which appear in both queries):

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = 'table1'
UNION ALL -- here use "UNION ALL" instead of "AND"
SELECT column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = 'table2';
```

Since you want to get data from the **same table**, you don't need two queries at all.

Just use an `IN` clause...

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name IN ('table1','table2');
```

...or use `OR`:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = 'table1' 
OR table_name = 'table2';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select 2 columns from different tables, you need to add some relation between them.

On the basis of that relationship, you can fetch data from two different tables.

Please check the link: https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join.asp

Hope it will solve your problem.